# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments when instantiate object SwiftUI IOS APP

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The errors show 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments' for each of the object instantiation in my roomList . The object should instantiate with parameters by default. Can someone helps me on this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
struct RoomListView: View {
        @State private var roomList : [Room] = [
            Room(images: "room-1",roomType: "Master Room", ownerID: "1", roomDescription: "@#!@$$", favouritedBy: "1,2", roomPrice: 30, contactPeriod: "Long", currentBookedBy: ""),
            Room(images: "room-1",roomType: "Master Room", ownerID: "1", roomDescription: "@#!@$$", favouritedBy: "1,2", roomPrice: 30, contactPeriod: "Long", currentBookedBy: ""),
            Room(images: "room-1",roomType: "Master Room", ownerID: "1", roomDescription: "@#!@$$", favouritedBy: "1,2", roomPrice: 30, contactPeriod: "Long", currentBookedBy: ""),
        ]
        
        
        var body: some View {
            List{
                ForEach(roomList){
                    room in RoomCardView(room: room)
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                }
            }
        }
```

Models/Room.swift

```
import Foundation 
struct Room: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    //    let id: String
    let images: String
    let roomType: String
    let ownerID: String
    let roomDescription: String
    let favouritedBy: String
    let roomPrice: Float
    let contactPeriod: String
    let currentBookedBy: String
    let updated_at: Double
    let created_at: Double
    
    init(images: String, roomType: String, ownerID: String, roomDescription: String, favouritedBy: String, roomPrice: Float, contactPeriod: String, currentBookedBy: String) {
        self.images = images
        self.roomType = roomType
        self.ownerID = ownerID
        self.roomDescription = roomDescription
        self.favouritedBy = favouritedBy
        self.roomPrice = roomPrice
        self.contactPeriod = contactPeriod
        self.currentBookedBy = currentBookedBy
        self.updated_at = Date()
        self.created_at = Date()
    }
}
```

Comment: In `Room`, you should have `let updated_at: Date` and `let created_at: Date` **not** Double.

Comment: You're assigning a `Date` to a value of type `Double`, fix that & you should be good to go

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine  Initially I was using Date, the Double just a try. I change to Date still not working

Comment: @Timmy Still cant

Comment: By the way, you don't need that init, just assign `Date()` to `updated_at` & `created_at`.

Comment: it works for me. Unless you have code that is relevant but not showing us. Presented my test code in the answer, since comments can't cope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I used for testing. It shows it works without any errors.

```
 import SwiftUI


struct Room: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    let images: String
    let roomType: String
    let ownerID: String
    let roomDescription: String
    let favouritedBy: String
    let roomPrice: Float
    let contactPeriod: String
    let currentBookedBy: String
    let updated_at: Date  // <-- here
    let created_at: Date  // <-- here
    
    init(images: String, roomType: String, ownerID: String, roomDescription: String, favouritedBy: String, roomPrice: Float, contactPeriod: String, currentBookedBy: String) {
        self.images = images
        self.roomType = roomType
        self.ownerID = ownerID
        self.roomDescription = roomDescription
        self.favouritedBy = favouritedBy
        self.roomPrice = roomPrice
        self.contactPeriod = contactPeriod
        self.currentBookedBy = currentBookedBy
        self.updated_at = Date()
        self.created_at = Date()
    }
}

struct RoomListView: View {
    @State private var roomList : [Room] = [
        Room(images: "room-1",roomType: "Master Room", ownerID: "1", roomDescription: "@#!@$$", favouritedBy: "1,2", roomPrice: 30, contactPeriod: "Long", currentBookedBy: ""),
        Room(images: "room-1",roomType: "Master Room", ownerID: "1", roomDescription: "@#!@$$", favouritedBy: "1,2", roomPrice: 30, contactPeriod: "Long", currentBookedBy: ""),
        Room(images: "room-1",roomType: "Master Room", ownerID: "1", roomDescription: "@#!@$$", favouritedBy: "1,2", roomPrice: 30, contactPeriod: "Long", currentBookedBy: ""),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(roomList){ room in
                Text(room.roomType)  // <-- here for testing
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RoomListView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I kinda understand the issue already, it worked if I move the Room.swift out of the Models folder and drag to the root.

Comment: don't understand what you mean, `..move the Room.swift out of the Models folder and drag to the root...`. Does this code work for you?

Comment: okay, it have bugs again, Invalid redeclaration of 'Room' and other attributes

Comment: I am getting this when I command + click the Room type

import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Room)
public class Room: NSManagedObject {

}

Comment: what are you talking about? Your comments make no sense at all.

Comment: Nothing, I find the issue is caused by my model file having conflict with the coreData. I defined the model in coreData but I went to create another model file to define the attributes and types and resut in the redeclaration error